# NORMINAL — normal or with nominal mistake?

Tags: meaning, terminology, orthography, writing, errors

At the very end of the live-stream for the nominal SpaceX STP-2 mission, the presenter places what appears to be a baseball cap onto the table. It reads "NORMINAL" (sic).

My first thought was *how embarrassing, they mixed up the spelling of "normal" and "nominal"*, but as English is clearly harder than rocket science, I'm turning to the appropriate authority on such matters.

Is "norminal" a normal word? If so, what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: [*Hi, can someone explain why SpaceX folks use "norminal" instead of "nominal?" Have anyone heard of this inside joke?*](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/79xjlo/what_is_norminal_joke/) Apparently, [It comes from this webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIHVPCj25Z0&feature=youtu.be&t=11m36s), which I *don't* intend to watch.

Answer (score 6):

*Lol,* **he's here making fun of another video. In the video [Intelsat 35e Launch Webcast](https://youtu.be/MIHVPCj25Z0) the narrator at 11:37 min** says

> **"Propulsion continues to be NORMINAL"**

instead of "Propulsion continues to be *normal*".

*Please check that other video, he's just making fun of the tongue slip.*

[image: Propulsion continues to be norminal]

Comment: You are right, except that it was actually supposed to be “Propulsion continues to be nominal”. “Nominal” is the space-engineer word for “normal”.

Answer (score 4):

Riya called it.  That ballcap is a huge shout-out to the SpaceX fanbase from SpaceX lead integration engineer John Insprucker (pictured), who first made the famous "norminal" verbal slip during the Intelsat 35E webcast Riya cited, and which has since made him quite the internet celebrity.  As a result of his popularity with those who follow SpaceX's launches, Insprucker typically hosts their most complex and interesting flights, and among the fanbase he's often known as "Daddy Insprucker."

One of SpaceX's most endearing qualities is that their webcasts are hosted not by professional journalists, but by wrench-turning engineers from the shop floor.  The chance to see some of the people at SpaceX who "make the magic happen" is much appreciated by the fan community.

Comment: Heh, appropriate user name.

Comment:  i am a girl.. So she not he...